# need help using curl for variables twice with batch

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off 
for /F %%I in ('curl https://ipinfo.io/ip') do set IP1=%%I 
for /F %%A in ('curl http://api.ipstack.com/%IP1%?access_key=mykey&format=1') do set IP=%%A 
echo %IP% pause
```

I can't figure out how to make the second curl use the variable I gave it, I don't understand what Ii did wrong

When I do

```
curl http://api.ipstack.com/%IP1%?access_key=mykey&format=1
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

The equals sign and the ampersand are causing you some issues here. Try wrapping the URL in quotes:

```
for /F %%A in ('curl "http://api.ipstack.com/%IP1%?access_key=mykey&format=1"') do set IP=%%A
```

and see if you get a better result. You may also want to use `curl -s` to suppress some of the headers that the CLI can return.

Comment: my problem is everything i try the result is get is the symbol }

Answer (score 0):

By using Delims=

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('curl -s https://ipinfo.io/ip') do set "IP1=%%I"
Echo %Ip1%
```

Output:

```
120.16.49.75
```

From the command line, I expect the following would work with the correct Key

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "USEBACKQ Tokens=* delims=" %A in (`"curl -s http://api.ipstack.com/%IP1%?access_key=mykey^&f                                                ormat=1"`) do set "IP=%~A"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP={"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=  "success": false,"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=  "error": {"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=    "code": 101,"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=    "type": "invalid_access_key","

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=    "info": "You have not supplied a valid API Access Key. [Technical Support: support@apila                                                yer.com]""

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=  }"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "IP=}"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

As an aside, the `}` you are being returned is the last piece of the error message being returned to the variable.